# How to ignore query error and continue to execute second query?

Tags: java, android, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am developing an app that retrieve data from SQL Server.

I have to execute 2 queries together to come out with result. The problem is the first query is a Stored Procedure that contain (INSERT INTO... EXEC sp_....), this query is shows error in server side but it is executed well, then the second query will read from the inserted result into it sue the first query.

The problem is, when the fist query execute, it make the App goes to Exception part which do not allow the second query to be executed.

Is there any way to make Android Studio ignore the error and execute the second query?

```java
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {
                Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
                if (con == null) {
                    message = "Error in connection with SQL server";
                } else {

                    String query = "EXEC [dbo].[sp_ReminderTimeToArriveTheBus]" +
                            " '"+str_wilayat+"','"+str_city+"', '"+str_station+"', '"+str_distnation+"', '"+currentTime+"'";

                    PreparedStatement stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                    rs.next();

                    String query2 = "SELECT OutputValue FROM [dbo].[FinalResultTable]";
                    PreparedStatement stmt2 = con.prepareStatement(query2);
                    ResultSet rs2 = stmt2.executeQuery();
                    str_min = rs2.getString("OutputValue");

                    if(rs2.next())
                    {
                        message = "O.K.";
                        str_min = rs2.getString("OutputValue");
                        isSuccess=true;
                    }
                    else{
                        isSuccess=false;
                    }
                    stmt.close();
                    rs.close();
                    stmt2.close();
                    rs2.close();

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                message = "Error";
            }
            return message;
        }
```

Comment: any help ? :'(...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve the issue through re-write the first query (the stored procedure) and it is executing without errors now. 
:)

Answer (score 0):

If i am understanding the question correctly is query2 should be executed in every situation. You can try running this query in place of "Return message"after catch clause.

Comment: How can I replace (return message;) with query2 ?

Comment: I mean to say add all the statements for prepare query before return message.